# SQL Server Group by guid but order entire query by most recent in group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I'd like to group things by a certain GUID but I want to order a single group by date (easy) and then order the entire results set based on the most recent record in each group and have that order listed as the results set. I want them to stick together. Does that make sense?

The best I could come up with is:

```
SELECT 
   ID, data, Date, 
   row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn 
FROM 
   MyTable
```

But this doesn't take into consideration the date for the entire results set.

Default table

```
ID      data                Date                        GUID
0       mapper started      2012-10-16 12:18:52     SessionID:[376f795a-dba2-49e1-8047-dbac9141d78b]
1       view models init    2012-10-16 12:18:53     SessionID:[2a1be1ce-606a-44ca-8400-75b7fd23d09a]
2       view load           2012-10-16 12:18:54     SessionID:[2a1be1ce-606a-44ca-8400-75b7fd23d09a]
3       mapper load         2012-10-16 12:18:55     SessionID:[376f795a-dba2-49e1-8047-dbac9141d78b]
4       view finished       2012-10-16 12:18:56     SessionID:[2a1be1ce-606a-44ca-8400-75b7fd23d09a]
5       mapper finished     2012-10-16 12:18:57     SessionID:[376f795a-dba2-49e1-8047-dbac9141d78b]
```

Query output I want:

```
ID      data                Date                         GUID
5       mapper finished     2012-10-16 12:18:57     SessionID:[376f795a-dba2-49e1-8047-dbac9141d78b]
3       mapper load         2012-10-16 12:18:55     SessionID:[376f795a-dba2-49e1-8047-dbac9141d78b]
0       mapper started      2012-10-16 12:18:52     SessionID:[376f795a-dba2-49e1-8047-dbac9141d78b]
4       view finished       2012-10-16 12:18:56     SessionID:[2a1be1ce-606a-44ca-8400-75b7fd23d09a]
2       view load           2012-10-16 12:18:54     SessionID:[2a1be1ce-606a-44ca-8400-75b7fd23d09a]
1       view models init    2012-10-16 12:18:53     SessionID:[2a1be1ce-606a-44ca-8400-75b7fd23d09a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a while but it seems it works:

```
select y.id, y.data, y.date, y.guid
from
  (select max(a.date) as date, a.guid
    from mytable a
    group by a.guid)x,
  (select id, data, date, guid, 
    row_number() over(partition by guid order by guid) as rn 
    from MyTable)y
where x.guid = y.guid
order by x.date desc, y.date desc;
```

SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cdc1/59

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The two joined selects in the from clause was the piece I was missing. That allowed each row in a group to be associated with the max date for that group. Which then allowed the results set to be sorted by most recent entry for every group.